# Unable to run Prolog in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, prolog

I've installed SwiProlog and PDT for Eclipse, made new process, consulted my file, where is only one row:

```
male(kalle).
```

It became green. but when I run in console:

```
male(kalle).
```

I've get

```
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_male] Undefined procedure: male/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there are two points which have to be clarified:

**First one (which I assume that affects your case):**

I tried to figure it out, seems that you have no file with rules. Prolog is working with rules so this means you need to write rules. Seems that in your case there are no rules yet, correct?

For more information about prolog kindly have a look at: [Fact and Rules](http://lpn.swi-prolog.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch1)

**Second one:**

I assume that you already got also the Ecclipse Marketplace *ProDT*?

In case not please follow the instructions there:

1. Launch Ecclipse
2. Go to "Help" > "Ecclipse Marketplace"
3. In Marketplace search "Prolog Development Tools (ProDT)"

For more information see link: [Programm Development Tools](https://www.swi-prolog.org/IDE.html)

Afterwards you can start with the first point.

Comment: I've made a file test.pl, there is one row "male(kalle).". I've consulted this file in Eclipse, so it turns green. Before using Eclipse I've used Prolog on line via https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ and there is pretty simple, you are writing rules and facts in the window and then run commands in console. I've thought that workflow in Eclipse have to be similar. The first difference I've learned is that in Eclipse it's needed to make a process.